# Is asking whether a particular question fits within the scope of a certain community within the scope of its corresponding meta site?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, off-topic, scope

If I have a question in mind, but I'm unsure whether it fits the the scope or is allowed in a certain Stack Exchange community, can I ask whether it would be allowed to ask it in the corresponding meta site?

Comment: Well that's what we have meta sites for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Yes, this sort of question is on topic for a site's meta.

The help article ["What is "meta"? How does it work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) states:

> Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow rather than discussing programming itself. It is separated from the main Q&A to reduce noise there while providing a legitimate space for people to ask how and why this site works the way it does. Meta is for...
>
> - ...Stack Overflow users to communicate with each other about Stack Overflow (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions)

Asking if a question is on topic for the main site is clearly within this scope. I've quoted from StackOverflow, but the article is the same on every network site.

Many meta sites even have tags dedicated to exactly this sort of question, on Stack Overflow it is the [[scope]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope?tab=Newest) tag, or for a non-SO example, Roleplaying Games has the [[on-topic]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic) tag.

Answer (score 1):

Well - if it's clearly a check of scope, yes.

Comment: Even if the question hasn't been asked yet?

Comment: If it had been already asked, it would be a dupe